# logo and menu not showing up on wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've made a website and I made it online. everything was fine. After a while the logo and menu disappeared and a text with the name of the site appeared in the top left of the site. i can not seem to understand where that text comes from or what happened with the menu. The menu is situated right top and the logo left top. If I look in the admin part, everything seems to be alright. If I put a backup, the site goes well and after some days that text appears again.
You can see the site at:

http://aureliavisinescu.com/

I tried to uninstall the plugins to see if one of them is making the changes but no luck. I can't see the problem and hope you can.

!!! So i figured it out...I modified the header.php and wordpress was constantly deleting my file.I changed the name of the header in header2.php and call it this way and the problem is solved..

Comment: some script effect remove topbar div

Answer (score 0):

When inspecting the elements in the browser the console puts out a 404 not found for one of your images. I don't know if this is your logo or just a random image which is not showing up ??

http://aureliavisinescu.com/wp-content/themes/attractor/images/kubrickbg-ltr.jpg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I don't know where that image is coming up..it's not an image uploaded by me

Comment: could you edit you post and add the html of your header please.